# How to Resample a List in Sverchok Nodes

Tags: procedural, mathematics, sverchok

I am trying to take a list of values and manipulate it to increase the number of items (floats in this case) in the list, while maintaining the "pattern" of the list. Take for instance the list output from the following nodes:

[image]

For this output, the values follow a sine wave pattern. I would like to increase the number of items in the list to say 100, while maintaining the sine wave pattern. Obviously this could be done by just increasing the count value in the Number Range node, but I am looking to do this after the output of the Sine Oscillator node.

Thanks,

Comment: One cheap and not very accurate way would be, you calculate the deltaX and deltaY from 2 neighboring values, divide by 2 and these are your new coordinates.  Of course you have to do this for all values you have except the last one (because you have no „next“ value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use, for example, "Vector Interpolation" node.

[image: Vector interpolation]

Similarly, you can use one of curve interpolation nodes, like "Cubic spline", or "NURBS Interpolating curve", or "RBF curve", if you wish a certain algorithm of resampling.